# FIPS 140-2 compliance and RSA encryption

Tags: rsa, standards, fips-140

I remember reading that the RSA algorithm was only permitted for encryption when used to encrypt a symmetric key (essentially leading to hybrid encryption).

However, reading through [Annex A: Approved Security Functions for FIPS PUB 140-2](https://csrc.nist.gov/csrc/media/publications/fips/140/2/final/documents/fips1402annexa.pdf) this doesn't seem to be an option.

Did I mis-remember? Are there any approved asymmetric encryption algorithms?

Comment: The user guide for BouncyCastle, a FIPS-certified crypto module in Java, mentions that there are no approved asymmetric key algorithms. RSA amd Elgamal may be allowed for other functions like key wrapping and key transport. https://downloads.bouncycastle.org/fips-java/BC-FJA-UserGuide-1.0.2.pdf

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a difference between FIPS approved and FIPS allowed algorithms.  RSA is an allowed algorithm for doing key wrap and key transport, however it's not FIPS approved for that purpose.  It's only approved for digital signatures.

If you're using a FIPS validated module take a look at the security policy for the module you're using and see if RSA is allowed or not for key wrap or key transport.  It **must** be documented there.  If it's not then you can't use it (and claim compliance) even if it's available in the module.

And no, there are no approved generic asymmetric encryption algorithms, they're only approved for digital signatures.